# Link to download Cassini source code?

Tags: webserver, cassini

Does any one know from where can I download source code for Cassini. I tried the link http://www.asp.net/Projects/Cassini/Download but this page does not exist now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx) there are also older versions on the website for the 2.0 framework for instance.

Answer (score 5):

A newer version was released: [Cassini 3.5.0.2: Support for Friendly URLs / Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2009/04/23/cassini-support-for-friendly-urls-routing.aspx)